# React Native App upgrade issue with libraries

Tags: android, react-native, native, react-native-maps, react-native-upgrade

Just received a kinda messy application from a client which was taken down by playstore due to version outdate

Task:
Update this applications libraries to latest. Application currently using react-native-cli with react-native 0.63.4 and want to upgrade to 0.72.0. Don't want to migrate to expo right now, and my main focus is for the android side only right now

Problem :
Not able to get clear roadmap of updation and getting multiple issues

Things I've Tried :

Firstly, with the help of react-native-upgrade-helper, I did whatever changes I had to do in all the files. Made build in Android Studio after that, but I came across the error,
"could not find method addUnimodulesDependencies() for arguments [] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler."

So i found out this client was using unimodules for a lot of his libraries. But unimodules has been deprecated and merged into expo now. So now I followed the instructions here, and it looks like I just have migrated my application into expo only as it(expo-upgrade) created created a .expo folder now and also bumped package.json libraries to latest versions.

I admit I do not have a clear roadmap of how to do upgradations in app. If someone can help a brother out here.